# How do I simplify this VBA switch statement to not repeat so much code?

Tags: vba, excel, switch-statement

I am writing an Excel macro that copies information from 1 worksheet and pastes it to another. It has to search for a specific string of text to identify the right column to copy, and I'm using a switch statement to go through the various columns. It's going all the way to `Z`, so it's very long macro. I also need to use this for several search terms, which makes the macro too large.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
Select Case True
  Case Range("A1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Case Range("B1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Case Range("C1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Case Range("D1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Case Range("E1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

It's going through the columns 1 by 1 to see if it contains a specific search term. If it does, it copies everything underneath it and pastes it starting in cell `L2` on a separate worksheet. It's just a very long macro and I'm trying to simplify it. Would a For loop work?

Comment: That really isn't the way a select case was intended to be used.Do you want more than one copy & paste operation to take place if multiple conditions resolve true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your variant has been updated if you prefer this method

```
With Sheets("ExportSheet")
Select Case True
    Case .[A1].Value = "SearchTerm1"
        .Range("A2:A" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Sheets("Template").[L2]
    Case .[B1].Value = "SearchTerm1"
        .Range("B2:B" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Sheets("Template").[L2]
    Case .[C1].Value = "SearchTerm1"
        .Range("C2:C" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Sheets("Template").[L2]
    ' and so on
End Select
End With

End Sub
```

2. Optimal variant imho is `Find` method

```
Sub test2()
Dim x&, y&
On Error GoTo errorhandler
    With Sheets("ExportSheet")
        y = .Rows(1).Find("SearchTerm1").Column
        x = .Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(2, y), .Cells(x, y)).Copy Sheets("Template").[L2]
    End With
Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    MsgBox "There is no 'SearchTerm1' in 'ExportSheet'!"
End Sub
```

3. `For each` looping through the range of cells also optimal I think

```
Sub test3()
Dim Cl As Range
For Each Cl In Sheets("ExportSheet").[A1:E1]
    If Cl.Value = "SearchTerm1" Then
        Sheets("ExportSheet").Range(Cl.Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0), _
            Cells(Rows.Count, Cl.Column).End(xlUp).Address(0, 0)).Copy _
        Sheets("Template").[L2]
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you are actually looking for the header from which you need to copy the data. If that is so:

```
With Sheets("ExportSheet")
    Dim r As Range: Set r = .Range("1:1").Find("SearchTerm1")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then 
        .Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Sheets("Template").Range("L2")
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any data to test on but this may work (Replace all the code you posted with this):

```
Dim X As Long
For X = 0 To 4
    If Range("A1").Offset(0, X).Value = "SearchTerm1" Then
        Sheets("ExportSheet").Range("A2").Offset(0, X).Resize(Sheets("ExportSheet").Range("A2").Offset(0, X).End(xlDown).Row - 2, 1).Copy
        Sheets("Template").Range("L2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  All of the actions within the function were the same except for the original cell to select, so just make it an input to a function.

```
Function copy_data(cell)
    Sheets("ExportSheet").Select
    Range(cell).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Function

Select Case True
  Case Range("A1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    copy_data("A2")
  Case Range("B1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    copy_data("B2")
  Case Range("C1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    copy_data("C2")
  Case Range("D1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    copy_data("D2")
  Case Range("E1").Value = "SearchTerm1"
    copy_data("E2")
End Select
```

Comment: I believe that function should be another sub with a passed in range parameter. Avoiding `.Select` and using `.Copy Destination...` would be another step.